# Vuelidate - dynamic schema validation in collection

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation, vuejs2, vuelidate

how do i get to work collection validation with a dynamic schema?
I have a list of person. Each have name and surname and a checkbox to choose if they have an address. Based on that state of that checkbox the address object should be validated or not independent for every person.
My collection validation looks like this:

```
  return {
    $each: {
      name: {
        required,
        minLength: minLength(2),
        maxLength: maxLength(255),
        noNums: not(helpers.regex('nums', /\d/))
      },
      surname: {
        required,
        minLength: minLength(2),
        maxLength: maxLength(255),
        noNums: not(helpers.regex('nums', /\d/))
      },
      hasAddress: {},
      address: getAddressValidations(),
    }
  };
```

Now if i want to add those adress validations should depend on the value of hasAdress. How to do this?
$each is static so i don't know how to make it depended on a sibling value for each person individually.

Comment: Don't know. I don't have access to this project anymore.